# MacBook Pro(Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) trackpad is not working after Catalina update

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, gesture

My MacBook Pro trackpad cursor and gestures stopped working after Catalina update.

I tried the following:

1. logged in to safe mode and reset it.
2. SMC reset.
3. NVRAM or PRAM reset
4. deleted plist files and restart.
5. updated to macOS Big Sur

I am able to click the trackpad button and particular checkbox/button where cursor is already present gets clicked. But cursor and gesture operation stopped. Also tried setting up different gesture operations.

I noticed the following in system information from About Mac that my trackpad is pointing to 'com.apple.perference.trackpad' plist file but that file is missing from that library location. [image]

Comment: I believe you won't be able to see/modify system files without disabling both SIP and the new Signed System Volume (SSV) Apple has introduced in Big Sur. As I'm not familiar how SSV works (yet), I'd approach Apple if you can. In the interim, maybe you can try using a USB mouse and/or disable trackpad when USB mouse is plugged in. You can disable trackpad in System Preferences > Accessibility > Pointer Control. Enabling/disabling the trackpad may rewrite the trackpad plist, but I can't guarantee this.

Comment: I have disabled SIP and SSV now. I am currently using usb mouse only. I tried updating the pointer control option. But its still the same.